# How to add tooltip to text form field in extjs6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have function for creating/rendering input fields but i don't know how to add tool tip on it in EXTjs6

this is my function:

```
createInputField: function(value, fieldsMarginBottom, readonly) {
        var fieldStyle = this.getFieldStyle(readonly);
        var nameField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            name: 'name',
            readOnly: true,
            hideLabel: true,
            value: value,
            width: this.fieldWidth,
            style: {
                marginBottom: fieldsMarginBottom + 'px'
            },
            //My try which is not working
            tooltip: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                renderer: function(tip, item){
                    tip.setTitle('name');
                    tip.update('Count: ');
                }
            },
            fieldStyle: fieldStyle
        });
        return nameField;
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I'll provide. Thank you

Comment: Where in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html) did you find the `tooltip` configuration?

Comment: I haven't. I was googling around how to, but nothing seems to work. Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As can be seen in [the `textfield` docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html), fields do not have a way to add a tooltip to their configuration, so you would have to create the tooltip manually.

If you look at [the docs for `Ext.tip.ToolTip`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html) how to do that, you may find a small example, where you just have to change the target as per [the `target` configuration description](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html#cfg-target):

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: nameField.getEl(),
    html: 'Press this button to clear the form'
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Its my firs time working with EXTJS and i didn't know you can reference target this way

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is correct. Here is example of generic function which you write once and use wherever you required in project by using using attributes.

```
addToolTip : function (id, msg) {
    new Ext.ToolTip({
            target : id,
            dismissDelay : 0,
            anchor : 'right',
            html : msg
        });
};
```