# How to ave multiple placeholders in a single textarea of an Extjs form

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to get a view as in the image.  I'm using Ext js form.  Any suggestions? If it was a single line, it wouldn't have been a problem. But the UX needs the textbox to be similar to that.

[image]

Comment: Hi do you mean multline?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189223/can-you-have-multiline-html5-placeholder-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300286/how-to-add-tooltip-to-text-form-field-in-extjs6/38301855#38301855

Comment: To get placeholder exactly like in the image, only possibility is a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
textarea {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
span {
  color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  content: "Max 180 characters";
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 10px));
  white-space: nowrap;
}
textarea:focus + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<textarea placeholder="Please provide additional information" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
  <span>Max 180 characters</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Appreciate it. Got a change from UX with the line Max 180 Chars under the text box and it has to count down as they type.